# Logistic regression model predict only class 0

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, logistic-regression, predict

I try to apply a model of logistic regression on my data. I realized that my model predict only class [0]
code:

```
logisticRegr = LogisticRegression()
logisticRegr.fit(X_train, y_train)
predictions = logisticRegr.predict(X_test)
```

What can i do to solve this problem please?

Comment: Your code snippet is not very helpful. My guess is `X_train` and `y_train` only contain examples for class `0` or you're not even fitting the training data. What is your accuracy of the model on training data?

Comment: the accuracy : 0.98. My y_train contains the two classes 0 and 1.

Comment: How imbalanced are your classes? Maybe try `logisticRegr = LogisticRegression(class_weight='balanced')`

Comment: now it works thank you! I shold balance the data before thats why?